# How to handle id not exist in DB while user change id in url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url

if someone change ID variable value in `http://localhost:8000/SendSMS/1` url then how to show own error message instead of machine error.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Checkout laravel findorfail https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you can use middleware to make sure the user has proper permission to see the page. If they do not you can redirect them.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

Comment: `{!!Form::open(['action' => ['UserController@messageSend',$random], 'method' => 'post'])!!}` It's not passing value of $random.

Comment: try {{ Form::open(array('action' => array('UserController@messageSend', $random))) }}, Laravel does POST by default.